# Does Android provide a calendar algorithm ready for development?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm starting the research to develop my Android's calendar, and I would like to know if there's any calendar or algorithm for calendar provided by the Android system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a built in calendar class. It's pretty robust. You'll probably want to use the GregroianCalendar concrete class.

[GregorianCalendar class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Comment: I think Tom is talking about DatePicker widget implementation in Android - not about Gregorian or other calendar's

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can make use of the google calendar and gData if required.